# webpack2 tslint errors on polyfills.ts

Tags: angular, webpack-2, tslint

I'm trying to set up my own webpack2/angular2
boilerplate but when I add tslint I've got this
bunch of error:

```
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: Error
    at new FatalError (/Users/webpack/angular2-webpack2-starter/node_modules/tslint/lib/error.js:33:23)
    at Function.findConfiguration (/Users/webpack/angular2-webpack2-starter/node_modules/tslint/lib/configuration.js:97:15)
    at resolveOptions (/Users/webpack/angular2-webpack2-starter/node_modules/tslint-loader/index.js:26:64)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/webpack/angular2-webpack2-starter/node_modules/tslint-loader/index.js:110:17)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:7000 ./src/polyfills.ts

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: Error
    at new FatalError (/Users/webpack/angular2-webpack2-starter/node_modules/tslint/lib/error.js:33:23)
    at Function.findConfiguration (/Users/webpack/angular2-webpack2-starter/node_modules/tslint/lib/configuration.js:97:15)
    at resolveOptions (/Users/webpack/angular2-webpack2-starter/node_modules/tslint-loader/index.js:26:64)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/webpack/angular2-webpack2-starter/node_modules/tslint-loader/index.js:110:17)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:7000 ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/vendor.ts
Module build failed: Error
    at new FatalError (/Users/webpack/angular2-webpack2-starter/node_modules/tslint/lib/error.js:33:23)
    at Function.findConfiguration (/Users/webpack/angular2-webpack2-starter/node_modules/tslint/lib/configuration.js:97:15)
    at resolveOptions (/Users/webpack/angular2-webpack2-starter/node_modules/tslint-loader/index.js:26:64)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/webpack/angular2-webpack2-starter/node_modules/tslint-loader/index.js:110:17)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:7000 ./src/vendor.ts
```

This is my setup

### webpack.common.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


const helpers = require('./helpers');

const METADATA = {
  title: 'Angular2 Webpack2',
  baseUrl: '/',
  isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer()
};
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor':    './src/vendor.ts',
    'main':      './src/main.ts'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'tslint-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [
          '@angularclass/hmr-loader',
          'awesome-typescript-loader',
          'angular2-template-loader',
          'angular-router-loader'
        ],
        exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loaders: ['html-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
          loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap'
        }),
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'bundle.css', disable: false, allChunks: true }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      title: METADATA.title,
      metadata: METADATA,
      inject: 'body',
      hash: true
    }),
    new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        options: {
            tslint: {
                emitErrors: true,
                failOnHint: true
            }
        }
    })
  ]
};
```

### webpack.dev.js

```
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
  ],

  devServer: {
    port: 7000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal',
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000
    }
  }
});
```

and for instance my

### polyfills.ts

```
// Polyfills

// import 'ie-shim'; // Internet Explorer 9 support


// import 'core-js/es6';
// Added parts of es6 which are necessary for your project or your browser support requirements.

// TEST
const ENV = 'developer';

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-set';
import 'core-js/es6/typed';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
// see issue https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/709
// import 'core-js/es6/promise';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

// Typescript emit helpers polyfill
import 'ts-helpers';

if ('production' === ENV) {
  // Production


} else {
  // Development

  Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

  require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');

}
```

### tslint.json

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      true,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces"
    ],
    "label-position": true,
    "label-undefined": true,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      "static-before-instance",
      "variables-before-functions"
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-key": true,
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": true,
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-unused-variable": true,
    "no-unreachable": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
      "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],

    "directive-selector-name": [true, "camelCase"],
    "component-selector-name": [true, "kebab-case"],
    "directive-selector-type": [true, "attribute"],
    "component-selector-type": [true, "element"],
    "use-input-property-decorator": true,
    "use-output-property-decorator": true,
    "use-host-property-decorator": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-selector-prefix": [true, "my"],
    "component-selector-prefix": [true, "my"],
    "pipe-naming": [true, "camelCase", "my"]
  }
}
```

What's the problem, please?
Thanks in advance.

### REPO

just in case 
https://bitbucket.org/whisher/angular2-webpack2-starter

### WORKED IT OUT

You should add **codelyzer** in your package.json

Comment: Great @Whisher! I missed the codelyzer in middle of all the error messages. npm should really improve these messages. Some are ok to ignore, others are the actual root cause.